# Beautifulsoup For loop got only prints few

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm really new to BeautifulSoup and Python.
I'm trying to parse a website, I'm getting what i need but, normally the website is showing all events in one page, when i print everything via for loop. It prints out just first 5 of the events. When i turned javascript of on Chrome Settings, there is a button, "Click for more..." , and there are only 5 events showing. Normally there are more than 40 events. If i ignore that button somehow, or press that button, i can solve my problem...

```
events = soup.find_all("tr", {'class' : 'event-details'})
for i in events:
    event = i.find("a")
    event_name = i.find("p", {'class' : 'name'})
    event_date = i.find("div", {'class' : 'date'})
    event_time = i.find("div", {'class' : 'time'})
    event_comments = i.find("div", {'class' : 'comments'})
    print("EVENTS")
    print(event["title"])
    print(event_name.text)
    print(event_date.text)
    print(event_time.text)
    print(event_comments.parent)
```

My question is how can i get all the data, what should i use, I tried selenium but it was a bit difficult, i don't know how to use them together in code.

Comment: Which website? Do you have w URL I can test with?

Comment: Did yo try with ```soup.findAll``` ?